# Competition puzzles?

Tags: discussion

I'm thinking of posting a challenge, which is like so:

---

Generate an equation which approximates as many digits of pi as possible. However, you are only allowed to use:

- the digits $1 - 9$ once and ONLY once
- $+,-,*,/$ (basic operators)
- $!$ (and its cousins, $!!$, $!!!$, etc.)
- exponents (e.g. $2^3$)
- roots (e.g. $\sqrt{2}$, $\root{3}\of{4}$)

  - in the first example for square roots, that only counts as one $2$ being used, while the second example counts as a $3$ and a $4$ being used.
- ceiling function, floor function
- decimal point
- recursion

You have 7 days to create an equation. You're allowed to change your personal equation however you want after you've posted it.

After 7 days, the equation with the most digits of $\pi$ wins. In case of a tiebreaker, the closer equation to pi wins.

---

The specs for the challenge aren't crystal-clear yet, and I know that it still needs some revising, but that's the basic gist of the challenge. I don't know if a challenge like this will be approved of in the Puzzling community, because this is a competition-type puzzle - the answer could be anything, and there's no single definitive answer (there's a winning criterion, however).

Are challenges like these acceptable?

Comment: Don't do the 7 days part, just keep it going. f you want that kinda thing, you're better off going into PPCG. But with out the 7 days, we call it open-ended

Comment: Whilst I'm not *personally* a fan of [tag:open-ended], there is certainly precedence for this sort of thing, such as [this one, which is very similar to your proposal](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/12325/5208) (though ironically without the open ended tag...)